# Regex help - matching not a specific string but not everything else?

Tags: regex

I'm trying not to match "logging 10.1.1.1".
So the Regex must match "logging 10.2.2.2" and "logging 10.3.3.3" and ANY other variation of "logging x.x.x.x". Must not match "ABC" as well.

Data Below

`logging 10.1.1.1
logging 10.2.2.2
logging 10.3.3.3
ABC`

I'm using Microsoft .NET Regex.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Pulling my hair out!

Comment: What is the pattern? Is it `("logging" (literal text)) [space] number (dot) number (dot) number (dot) number`? Do the last 3 numbers have to match?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, your question is not clear as to precisely what the rules for matching are. For example, it is not clear whether `logging 9.1.2.3` would be a match or not given the two examples of a "must match."

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^(?!.*logging 10\.1\.1\.1|ABC).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Q5RuZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely impossible to get the right answer given how the question is posed, but it sounds like you want this:

```
\blogging\s(?!10.1.1.1)(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b
```

The expression will match *only* the pattern 'logging x.x.x.x' *except* 'logging 10.1.1.1'.

In C#,

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\blogging\s(?!10.1.1.1)(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b");
string data = "logging 10.1.1.1\r\nlogging 10.2.2.2\r\nlogging 8.8.8.8\r\nABC";

foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(data)) System.Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Outputs to console

```
logging 10.2.2.2
logging 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. My application needs a single line regex though :/, using solarwinds NCM and it's to manage configs, I basically want to delete all "logging x.x.x.x" except "logging 1.1.1.1"

Comment: I basically want to delete all "logging x.x.x.x" except "logging 10.1.1.1" AND not match anything else.